# How can I use the #error directive to provide the user pointers to useful information?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

Suppose I have a file like the following

`Mainfile.cpp`

```
 #include "stdafx.h"
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include "Myfile.h"
    #ifdef _MYFILE
    #error Myfile.h to be included. Please refer Ream Me at C:\ReadMe
    #endif


    int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
    {
    system("pause");
        return 0;
    }
```

`Myfile.h`

```
#pragma once
#undef _MYFILE
#define MYFILE
```

My goal is to provide additional information ("Please refer to ....") in case something is missing (MyFile.h was not included/found on the path).

How can I handle this with a third party library, like Boost? In this case, I don't have control on `Boost` and I cannot handle the definition of _MYFILE: then how can throw the error?

`Pseudo code`

```
#include "boost/boost.h"
#if (boost is not included || directory path is not set || boost .h file not found)
   #error: Set boost path and compile again
#endif
```

Comment: Isn't it enough that he will get a compiler error saying "Include file 'boost/boost.h' not found"?  And in your first example, surely you'll get "Include file 'Myfile.h' not found" from the compiler before your custom error message?

Comment: @RichieHindle: Ya you are right. But as per requirement if the user is completly novice then how to go after this. So, #error will throw an error and suggesting that pls read the ReadMe file located in your project drive

Comment: @RichieHindle: Like __cplusplus, is there anything caleed __boost or something like that. Because I tried in Google and all that but unable to fine it

Comment: But does your example actually work?  When I try to compile a C++ file with a missing `#include`, the compilation stops at that point.  It doesn't get as far as your `#error`.

Comment: @RichieHindle: Yes it is working. `fatal error C1189: #error :  "Myfile.h to be included. Please refer Ream Me at C:\ReadMe"`

Comment: You should have a look at specific headers you're using from boost. You may refer to their include guard definition to throw an error.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the question, but names that begin with an underscore followed by a capital letter (`_MYFILE`) and names that contain two consecutive underscores are reserved to the implementation. Don't use them.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't

```
#if _MYFILE
#error Myfile.h to be included. Please refer Ream Me at C:\ReadMe
#endif
```

be

```
#ifndef _MYFILE
#error Myfile.h to be included. Please refer Ream Me at C:\ReadMe
#endif
```

Comment: No, the #error syntax simply wants random tokens. You can put quotes around the message, but then you'll see them again in the compiler message, and possibly end up with double quotes.

Comment: @SebastianRedl: I believe the important difference is `#if` vs. `#ifndef`, not whether the error is quoted or not.

Comment: @RichieHindle Ah, that makes sense. I was distracted by the quotes. And yes, using `#ifndef` would be correct here; the `#if` will generally work if you reverse the condition, I think, but may cause additional warnings from some compilers.

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to do what you want in C/C++ code. Once you enter `#include "myfile.h"` it is up to compiler to locate that file and throw an error if it's nowhere to be found.

You are also misusing `#ifndef ... #error ... #endif`.
Some people use it to track header dependencies; imagine you have a header `messages.h` which requires header `mytypes.h`. Usually you just write something like this:

// File mytypes.h

```
#ifndef MYTYPES_H
#define MYTYPES_H

typedef unsigned char UINT8;
// ...

#endif
```

// File messages.h

```
#ifndef MESSAGES_H
#define MESSAGES_H

#include "mytypes.h"

// ...     

#endif
```

But you can also write messages.h like that:

```
#ifndef MESSAGES_H
#define MESSAGES_H

#ifndef MYTYPES_H
#error I need mytypes.h to compile!
#endif

#endif
```

but it quickly becomes a chore to insert #errors for all the headers you depend on and then include those dependencies over and over again in all the source files where your header is needed. So in most cases first approach is the way to go.

You also need to decide what type of include guard you want to use. Don't `#define MYFILE` if you're already using `#pragma once`. Choose one and stick to it. (and remember that `#pragma once` is nonstandard).

Finally last but not least: if you really need to be that user friendly you will need to use your build system to verify that all extra libraries are installed and their headers are available. My guess is you're using Visual Studio's native builder. I don't know that one but I read it has pre-build actions so perhaps it's possible to define one which verifies boost location via some native visual studio calls or simply by running a batch file included in the project.